# Java - NoClassDefFound error with specified classpath

Tags: java, intellij-idea, classpath, spark-java

When I try to run my jar application, I get a NoClassDefFoundError even though i have referenced the library containing the class in my classpath.

This is the line causing it (in the start method of a thread):

```
Spark.staticFiles.location("/public");
```

This defines the location of static files for the Spark framework for java, and I have the spark library in the "lib" folder. The libraries are included in the jar:
[lib package in the jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3NOd.png)

My manifest file looks like this:

*Manifest-Version: 1.0*

*Class-Path: lib/* *

*Main-Class: com.xx.xx.xx.Main*

This should as far as I know mean that all libraries in *lib* is included, but if i run the jar with a simple *java -jar test.jar* i get this:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: spark/Spark
    at com.xx.xx.xx.Main.run(TundraWebApp.java:20)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: spark.Spark
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

spark/Spark being part of one of the libraries.

Why isn't my libraries detected?

Comment: Please share full code of class where you got exception, it will help other people to understand your case better and to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `Class-Path` supports wildcards. You'd have to spell out the jar names, e.g.:

```
Class-Path: libs/spark-core_2.11-2.3.0.jar libs/spark-sql_2.11-2.3.0.jar
```